# Full Text justification in android

Tags: android

I am browsing data from the server and getting through page.getContent(), My textview has default gravity(left), so text is left aligned, I want right alignment as well(As we justify text in MS Office)....Is there any way to justify the text.

I have put android:garavity="left|right" it also doesn't work.

```
TextView textview=(TextView)findViewbyId(R.id.text);
textview.setText(Html.fromHtml(page.getContent()));
```

Answer (score 2):

I came across same problem and didn't find any good solution so I write my own class, Here it is. 
Just you have to call the static justify function that takes two arguments and the class will do the rest of work for you :) Hope this will help.

1. Text View object
2. Content Width  (Total width of your text view)

//MainActivity

```
package com.fawad.textjustification;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    static Point size;
    static float density;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        size=new Point();
        DisplayMetrics dm=new DisplayMetrics();
        display.getMetrics(dm);
        density=dm.density;
        display.getSize(size);


        TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        Typeface typeface=Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), "Roboto-Medium.ttf");
        tv.setTypeface(typeface);
        tv.setLineSpacing(0f, 1.2f);
        tv.setTextSize(10*MainActivity.density);

        //some random long text
         String myText=getResources().getString(R.string.my_text);

         tv.setText(myText);
        TextJustification.justify(tv,size.x);


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

//TextJustificationClass

```
package com.fawad.textjustification;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TextJustification {

    public static void justify(TextView textView,float contentWidth) {
        String text=textView.getText().toString();
        Paint paint=textView.getPaint();

        ArrayList<String> lineList=lineBreak(text,paint,contentWidth);

        textView.setText(TextUtils.join(" ", lineList).replaceFirst("\\s", ""));
    }


    private static ArrayList<String> lineBreak(String text,Paint paint,float contentWidth){
        String [] wordArray=text.split("\\s"); 
        ArrayList<String> lineList = new ArrayList<String>();
        String myText="";

        for(String word:wordArray){
            if(paint.measureText(myText+" "+word)<=contentWidth)
                myText=myText+" "+word;
            else{
                int totalSpacesToInsert=(int)((contentWidth-paint.measureText(myText))/paint.measureText(" "));
                lineList.add(justifyLine(myText,totalSpacesToInsert));
                myText=word;
            }
        }
        lineList.add(myText);
        return lineList;
    }

    private static String justifyLine(String text,int totalSpacesToInsert){
        String[] wordArray=text.split("\\s");
        String toAppend=" ";

        while((totalSpacesToInsert)>=(wordArray.length-1)){
            toAppend=toAppend+" ";
            totalSpacesToInsert=totalSpacesToInsert-(wordArray.length-1);
        }
        int i=0;
        String justifiedText="";
        for(String word:wordArray){
            if(i<totalSpacesToInsert)
                justifiedText=justifiedText+word+" "+toAppend;

            else                
                justifiedText=justifiedText+word+toAppend;

            i++;
        }

        return justifiedText;
    }

}
```

//XML

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    tools:context=".MainActivity" 
    >



    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"

             >
            <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, full justification i.e. text flushed to the left and right, is not possible on Android as of API 14. I don't know if this support will be included in the future. You might want to try the following attribute in the layout of your `TextView`. Some people claim it worked for them (though it did not work for me):

```
android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
```